# PHP session isnot working

Tags: php, session, session-variables

php session isnot working !!! Any idea why it is passing null value to the senond page ??

```
file1.php:
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['lat']=$_POST['lat'];
$_SESSION['lng']=$_POST['lng'];
session_write_close();
header('Location: http://sample.com/e_health/searchambulance.php');
?>

file2:
<?php
session_start();
$lat= $_SESSION['lat'];
$lng=$_SESSION['lng'];
echo $lat;
echo $lng;
?>
```

Comment: both files are in same domain?

Comment: Did you check if the $_POST values actually exist? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Are you sure that your indexes(lat,lng) exist in $_POST? We need some more code to debug on that. Where are you posting from? Try, in your file1.php to do a var_dump($_POST);die(); at the very top.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two thing you might want to test:
a) does file1 get invoked with those two POST parameters?
b) does the propagation of the session id work? (for both "files" the output session_id=xyz must be identical or otherwise the second request isn't tight to the session of the first request)

file1:

```
<?php
if ( !isset($_POST['lat'], $_POST['lng']) ) {
    die('missing parameters'); // you probably want a slightly more sophisticated error handling here
}
session_start();
$_SESSION['lat']=$_POST['lat'];
$_SESSION['lng']=$_POST['lng'];

//session_write_close();
//header('Location: http://sample.com/e_health/searchambulance.php');
echo 'session_id=', session_id(), '<br /><a href="http://sample.com/e_health/searchambulance.php">page #2</a>';
```

file2:

```
<?php
session_start();
$lat= $_SESSION['lat'];
$lng=$_SESSION['lng'];
echo 'session_id=', session_id(), '<br />';
echo $lat;
echo $lng;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to this way. It will works......

file1.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['lat']=$_POST['lat'];
$_SESSION['lng']=$_POST['lng'];

header('Location: http://sample.com/e_health/searchambulance.php');
?>

file2:
<?php
session_start();
$lat= $_SESSION['lat'];
$lng=$_SESSION['lng'];
echo $lat;
echo $lng;
?>
```